# Comma in value not working when displaying price

Tags: javascript, parsing, numbers

I am having a problem displaying a price that is brought in from a PHP file by AJAX and then appended to the page via Javascript.

```
$('.cash1').text(parseFloat(prices[0]).toFixed(2));
```

This works fine until the returned value is in the thousands and contains a comma i.e. `1,123.34`.

I would really like to keep the comma in the value if possible but so far the script will only return the value `1.34`. I have tried using `parseInt` but this seems to fail in the same way.

Comment: You need an external library to parse that.

Comment: Juz replace the comma and format after calculations. ;)

Comment: @Amberlamps: You can do it manually, what I mean is that parsing locale numbers is not supported in JS by default. It depends on the language of user's computer. There are libraries to do this very easily.

Comment: In addition to other answers, you could always adjust the value in your PHP code, instead of the javascript (if indeed you need to adjust, since you can just treat the value as a string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this ok to you?

```
<script> 
.............
    $('.cash1').text(numberWithCommas(prices[0].toFixed(2)));
.............. 

function numberWithCommas(x) {
     var parts = x.toString().split(".");
     parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
     return parts.join(".");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting you need to work with float, you need to use [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method:

```
var n = prices[0].replace(',','');
$('.cash1').text(parseFloat(n).toFixed(2));
```

If you need for some purpose those commas, I suggest making a method that will make a string with commas from a float number when needed, and working with numbers any other time.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to parse it? Just use it as is (or as a string):

```
$('.cash1').text(prices[0].toString());
```